# Not able to add UIbutton to UIscrollview in Monotouch Dynamically

Tags: uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

I am facing a very strange problem. I am trying to add UIbuttons to a UIscrollview in Monotouch. But the UIbutton is not getting displayed.

Here is the code:

```
UIImage img = UIImage.FromFile("ecu.png");
UIButton btn = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
btn.SetBackgroundImage(img,UIControlState.Normal);
btn.Frame = new RectangleF(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width - 185, 0,    185,UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Height, 100, 150, 150);
btn.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView("Info","Tapped",null,"Ok",null);
            alert.Show();
        } ;
scrollimages.AddSubview (btn);
```

The same code works if i add the button to the View.
Can i get some help on this please.

Comment: Did you set UIScrollView.ContentSize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the following code after adding a UIScrollView to the View in Interface Builder:

```
    UIImage img = UIImage.FromFile("ecu.png");
        UIButton btn = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
        btn.SetBackgroundImage(img,UIControlState.Normal);
        btn.Frame = new RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, 150.0f);
        btn.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
            UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView("Info","Tapped",null,"Ok",null);
            alert.Show();
        } ;
        this.ScrollImages.AddSubview (btn);
```

and it works as expected. The odd thing seems to be you have 7 parameters for the RectangleF constructor. have you just tried setting the origin to 0,0 to see if a button is added there?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works now. I set the x and y co ordinates to 0 and its working fine

Comment: Hey just one small doubt. I have added an UIImageView for the same UIscrollview using   imageView.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Size.Width - 150, yadjustment, 150, 150);
   imageView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
   imageView.Tag = position;
   
   scrollimages.AddSubview (imageView); The Image view gets added in the scroll view which rotates circularly. But the same frame if i give to a UIbutton it fails. Any idea why??

Comment: Hey sorry for troubling u. I fixed the issue now. Thanks for the help